# Cant install RPM's in terminal window

Tags: server

I cant install RPM's through the terminal and logged in as root.

Command- apt-get install rpm

Output- RPM package is not available, package has no installation candidate.

Comment: `rpm` packages are intended for Red Hat-based distributions. Ubuntu is a Debian-based distribution. Ubuntu uses `deb` packages. Please edit your question to explain what you are trying to accomplish and why you need ill-fitting parts to do it.

Comment: Sorry about that, i was unaware of the difference.  Well that pretty much answered my question. Thanks.